# How to get float by integer / integer C lang

Tags: c

I wanna get 1.666667 by dividing 2*n+1 by 3 (n=2). and it always creates 1.000000 but i want 1.666667. I tried printing (2*n+1)/3 as a float but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing integer division and then assigning to a float.

Use

```
(2.0*n+1)/3
```

The `2.0` is a double and the whole expression is then converted to a double, which is assigned to a float giving you the result intended.